# Error when trying to migrate tables created with seguelizeCLI

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got an error when try to migrate tables which are created using seguelizeCLI in  node js,and when i change version of node js i also got different error message

1.this when i use stable node v9

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be one of type string, TypedArray, or DataView
    at Hash.update (internal/crypto/hash.js:53:11)
    at sha1 (/home/dontito/NodeORMs/node_modules/mysql2/lib/auth_41.js:30:8)
    at Object.token [as calculateToken] (/home/dontito/NodeORMs/node_modules/mysql2/lib/auth_41.js:64:16)
    at new HandshakeResponse (/home/dontito/NodeORMs/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/handshake_response.js:28:24)
    at ClientHandshake.sendCredentials (/home/dontito/NodeORMs/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/client_handshake.js:51:27)
    at ClientHandshake.handshakeInit (/home/dontito/NodeORMs/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/client_handshake.js:142:10)
    at ClientHandshake.Command.execute (/home/dontito/NodeORMs/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:40:20)
    at Connection.handlePacket (/home/dontito/NodeORMs/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:502:28)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (/home/dontito/NodeORMs/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:81:16)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/dontito/NodeORMs/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:77:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/dontito/NodeORMs/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:89:29)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:127:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:256:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:590:20)

2.when i turn to other node version like v4
crypto.js:100
  this._handle.update(data, encoding);
               ^

TypeError: Not a string or buffer
    at TypeError (native)
    at Hash.update (crypto.js:100:16)
    at sha1 (/home/dontito/NodeORMs/node_modules/mysql2/lib/auth_41.js:30:8)
    at Object.token [as calculateToken] (/home/dontito/NodeORMs/node_modules/mysql2/lib/auth_41.js:64:16)
    at new HandshakeResponse (/home/dontito/NodeORMs/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/handshake_response.js:28:24)
    at ClientHandshake.sendCredentials (/home/dontito/NodeORMs/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/client_handshake.js:51:27)
    at ClientHandshake.handshakeInit (/home/dontito/NodeORMs/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/client_handshake.js:142:10)
    at ClientHandshake.Command.execute (/home/dontito/NodeORMs/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:40:20)
    at Connection.handlePacket (/home/dontito/NodeORMs/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:502:28)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (/home/dontito/NodeORMs/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:81:16)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/dontito/NodeORMs/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:77:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/dontito/NodeORMs/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:89:29)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

Comment: have you resolved this issue ? i got the same error here.. any update on this ?

Comment: @SuganKrishna not yet,if you will get please try to share

Comment: yes i found a solutions. In my case, i have given password for my DB connection as INTEGER (in config/config.json) Need to provide password in quotes. Like this "password": "123", instead have given as "password": 123

Answer (score 0):

You should change your password in config file like abc → "abc"